# How to increase Drop rates in a minecraft spigot server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have made a spigot 1.16.5 server, but I was wondering that is there any plugin/setting/anything that I can do in order to change the drop rates of mobs.

I have seen many custom drop plugins but none of them have had an option to change the drop rate (Or at-least I didn't find such a option).

What I really wanted was as drowned spawning with tridents is already really rare, so I wanted to keep and 80% chance of trident dropping instead of the scarce chance that Mojang set up. I wanted to do the same with enderman drop rates.

Any help would be appreciated, and I am not just sticking to plugins, I am ready to achieve this in any method except for deleting my current world as I have good progress on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not build a [farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZCBqjvMtNs) instead?

Comment: Thanks! I will build it

Answer (score -1):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int newnumber = rand.nextInt(205); // The 205 is your number
if(newnumber < 20)
{
  p.getInventory().addItem(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
}
```

I don't know Java, but this *likely works* for you to calculate a chance for a Diamond Sword.

Or if you want a plugin to do it, try [this one](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/custom-drops-editor-1-13-1-16-easy-to-use-hard-not-to-want.71153/).

Comment: you havent really provided context for this code. Where does this go? How would you even used this? The code is very vague and doesn't really seem to make very much sense, it's a quick `if` then some item adding method

Comment: @Penguin I said I dont know java, this is literally the extent of my java knowledge I have no idea where this would go, presumably a plugin or jar file

Comment: I didn't get the code, but thanks for the plugin anyways.